# set html class to TextField in django model

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to change TextField in my model to TinyMCE RichTextEditor. I have downloaded tinymce 4.8.3 development package and customized it. Then I pasted tinymce files to staticfiles directory. As I understand it, in order for everything to work, I must assign an **HTML class for the <textarea> </textarea> element on the view page.** How it works on the local html file. I've tried almost all the applications that are installed through the pip(django-tinymce, django-tinymce4-lite etc..). And I still wanted to adjust this rich text editor for myself. Rich Text Editor must be appeared on admin page.

This is my models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)

    class Media:
        js = ('js/init-tinymce.js', 'js/tinymce/tinymce.js',)
```

admin.py:

```
class PostModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["title", "created"]
    list_display_links = ["title"]
    list_filter = ["created", "tags"]
    search_fields = ["title", "content",]
    class Meta:
        model = Post

admin.site.register(Post, PostModelAdmin)
```

Please explain to me if I understood something differently. I use Django 2.0.8 and python 3.6. On the Internet, I found how to set a class like in this form, but I can not add it to my project.

```
class MyTextForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyTextForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['content'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'tinymce'

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('content')  # your fields here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a form :

```
class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Post
        widgets = {
            'yourfieldname': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'your-class'})
        }
```

And now add it to you model admin :

```
class PostModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelAdminForm
```

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there with the code you have, just a few things:

- The nested `Media` class should be on the form or the widget, not on the model
- If you always want the same CSS class in several places, you can encapsulate it all in a Widget

To override the behaviour of the form used by the admin, you have 2 main options:

- set the `form` class attribute like in the other answer, but you have to implement the form
- override the default widget for a certain model field [using `formfield_overrides`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides), this way you just have to write a widget once.

Here is the widget code:

```
class AdminTinyMceWidget(AdminTextareaWidget):
    class Media:
        js = ('js/init-tinymce.js', 'js/tinymce/tinymce.js',)

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        if attrs is None:
            attrs = {'class': 'your-class'}
        super().__init__(attrs)
```

And the model admin setting `formfield_overrides`:

```
class PostModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': AdminTinyMceWidget()},
    }
```